# Agora providing messages hints in chat like LinkedIn does

Tags: chat, agora.io

Starting to implement a chat functionality in my app and wondering if there is something similar to LinkedIn messages hints within Agora.

Does Agora provide messages hints for real-time chat like on LinkedIn chats?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: you should consider putting some code and steps that you have tried, errors and so on. right now, your question reads like a general wonderment.

Answer (score 0):

Agora RTM SDK does not support typing indication feature for now. But you can send a signal to the remote users through the RTM SDK when a user is typing. When the remote users receive the signal, they can display the typing indication such as "User typing..." on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I wasn't too specific, sorry.

I meant to have hints without typing anything. On LinkedIn you can choose from proposed answers/questions when you're commenting a post. Does Agora provide anything like this?

Comment: Agora does not have this functionality for now.